Azure function App not listing the function
I have below function which i am trying to deploy from azure devops cd pipeline
import os
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Dict
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
sample = func.Blueprint()
 
@sample.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@sample.route(route="req")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> str:
    user = req.params.get("user")
    return f"Hellome, {user}!"

i can see the above function in my dev env which is having no restrictions where as my preprod configure using private endpoint and storage account linked also configured using private endpoint.
I am deploying in preprod using Openshift agent and service prinicpal from devops pipeline.
Checked the connectivity from azure functions to storage accounts - success
agent - using python3 and pip installed already
we are using python 3.10 and its available in the agent as well
requirements.txt having all the dependency.
deployment say success but the function is not listing in function app.
where as the same is working fine in my dev , and both function app having same plan and configuration.
If i remove the from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient from the function , i can see the code in both dev and preprod .
Service account has contributor role in both function app and storage acccount.
Is anyone faced these kind of issues? or need to validate something before deployment?
Regards,
Shan

Ensure azure-storage-blob is in requirements.txt, installed during deployment, and verify Function App runtime and private endpoint connectivity to the storage account in preprod.
